# How to close a text file that is opened through openDialogBox?

Tags: c#

I have created a button that opens a text file through openDialogBox1 and display the content in a listBox. Then I wanted to create another button to close this file, but I couldn't figure out what code to use. Can anyone help me please? Thank you.
Here is a sample of my openFile button code :

```
private void openButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        StreamReader inputFile;
        string File;

        OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
        openFileDialog1.DefaultExt = "txt";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*txt)|*txt";

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            inputFile = File.OpenText(openFileDialog1.FileName);
            fileListBox.Items.Clear();
            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
            {
                File = inputFile.ReadLine();

                fileListBox.Items.Add(File);
            }
            inputFile.Close();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid File!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Um... `inputFile.Close();` closes the file you use with `File.OpenText`...

Comment: `OpenFileDialog` just gives you the file path, not a `FileStream` (it doesn't open it). You are already opening *and* closing it with `OpenText(…)` and `Close()` methods. What you need is not clear.

Comment: You should use a `using()` statement to wrap the `File.OpenText` onward part of this code in order to ensure it's always closed even if there's an Exception. See example here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. What I wanted was to open the file with one button and close it with another button, but it didn't work. I will check the examples in the link and will try to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Declare   `StreamReader inputFile;` globally so it is available in the second button click.

However, the file should be opened and closed as soon as you are done with it to release resources. Plus, you don't know, the second button may never get clicked.